# Save and download PDF

Tags: php, dompdf

I need to do 2 things together & at the same time with DOMPDF.

I need to do the following together - is this possible?

```
//print the pdf file to the screen for saving
$dompdf->stream("pdf_filename_".rand(10,1000).".pdf", array("Attachment" => false));
//save the pdf file on the server
file_put_contents('/home/stsnew/public_html/pdf/file.pdf', $dompdf->output());
```

The above works fine if `$dompdf->stream` and `$dompdf->output()` are done separately/individually , but when I try to run them together as shown above, it just crashes.

Any help/advice would be really appreciated.

Comment: its good practice on SO to accept your chosen answer ... :-)

Comment: I have chosen your answer... apologies, I didn't know ;-)

Comment: Have a quick read of these http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Why dont you swap them round create the pdf first as a file and then stream the created file back ?

```
$file_to_save = '/home/stsnew/public_html/pdf/file.pdf';
//save the pdf file on the server
file_put_contents($file_to_save, $dompdf->output()); 
//print the pdf file to the screen for saving
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="file.pdf"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file_to_save));
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
readfile($file_to_save);
```

Answer (score 8):

Answering late but might be will help onward.

on set attachment true or 1

```
$dompdf->stream("pdf_filename_".rand(10,1000).".pdf", array("Attachment" => true));
```

No need of file_put_contents() if you are just looking for download